# Umbraco gets wrong current node?

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm experiencing an issue where my Umbraco project gets the wrong PublishedContent node when using UmbracoContext.Current.PublishedContentRequest.PublishedContent, it seems like it's getting the current node's parent.

This is probably a long shot as I really have no information to give as far as this question goes, I have no idea where it's going wrong. I didn't start this project, it's just been handed over to me and I have to finish it.

This Umbraco project has URL rewriting on the page where I can't get the current node. The page has several URL's and if I go to the canonical URL of the page, it can get the node just fine.

I'm hoping someone can help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the view for the page, if you get Model.Content.Id, is that the right node id? Where are you using UmbracoContext.Current.PublishedContentRequest.PublishedContent? Could you post some code, it might help to see where the issue is.

Comment: This is on the layout page, if I use Model.Content.Id it gets the wrong ID as well. I've found a fix that works for now, but I'm still really wondering what has gone wrong here. This Umbraco project is running sort of a MVVM-architecture, so I have Models for each document type and ViewModels for each template. The models and viewmodels are getting all the correct information just fine, which means I just used Umbraco.TypedContent(Model.Id) and got my node through that. The "Model" being the ViewModel used in the view.

It's quite confusing, my explanation probably doesn't make much sense. :/

Answer (score 1):

Umbraco has a default feature called alternative template: if a template has the alias **Tpl** and you go to /Page/**Tpl** umbraco will render the Page node with the Tpl template, exactly like if you were calling /Page/?altTemplate=Tpl.

So maybe your issue is to have a url that has the template name in it. 
If that's the case you can rename that template alias to something else or remove this behavior by editing the file
 ~/config/404handlers.config, removing the line that contains

```
<notFound assembly="umbraco" type="SearchForTemplate" />.
```